# Tmux stuck in copy-mode

Tags: shell, tmux

After performing a keyboard shortcut in tmux (I am not sure which), I am put into a state of perpetual copy-mode. I can type normally, but every time I hit the `n` key it prompts to `gotoline` input.

If I close the pane it happens even on the new pane I have created.

Any help on how to exit this once it happens would be great, as all documentation surrounding copy-mode states that when you hit `Esc` or `q` you should leave copy-mode.

Comment: Does `Ctrl-C` work any better?

Comment: Dealing with the same problem. `Ctrl-C` does not resolve it.

Comment: Ran into the same problem but I just was in capslock.

Answer (score 12):

Typically I get out of copy mode using <kbd>Enter</kbd>. On another machine with different desktop environment and different terminal, this doesn't work in tmux. But I did find a way.

If you look at the definition of the cancel key in copy mode ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>  ) that's defined as

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-c               send-keys -X cancel
```

That means you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to enter command mode and then execute

```
send-keys -X cancel
```

This will take you out of copy mode.

Variation on the theme would be to change your key mode to vi ( unless you already use that or your `EDITOR` environment variable already set to it):

```
set -g mode-keys vi
```

This allows hitting `q` in copy mode to cancel the said mode

---

As for how to deal with the problem of <kbd>n</kbd> key and `gotoline`, I can't answer that. I'd suggest trying different terminal emulator or keyboard, since the issue may not be related to tmux at all.

Comment: As a sidenote, I don't know which version of tmux you're using but in version 2.9a pressing `q` exits the copy mode and I'm not even using vi keybindings. Also I found out `ctrl+c`, `ctrl+x`, `ctrl+v` to be working (and the keybindings are not even referenced into the help menu). hope it helps.

Comment: I find myself back here after over a year with the same problem (`n` key / goto line issue), this time with tmux 3.0a. It's definitely tmux, and nothing else that causes this. Still no solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your current tmux key bindings by running `tmux list-keys`. If you see a binding that matches

```
bind-key -T root n <command>
```

then the `n` key is bound in the root table. This means that pressing `n` in the shell at all will cause `<command>` to be run. You can remove the binding by running

```
tmux unbind -T root n
```

I ran into this issue while using the tmux plugin [tmux-copycat](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-copycat), which adds some alternative bindings for copy/paste functionality. Following the above instructions resolved it.

Comment: in my case also it was related to this plugin.